# How to fix "Invalid login token." when trying to use authenticated user with AWS and Cognito User Pool

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have set up a Xamarin platform app which handles user login through AWS Cognito User Pools, which works. However when I try to access additional AWS services I get the "Invalid login token." error.

In the AWS console I have set up a User Pool with an App Client as well as an Identity Pool that uses Cognito as it's Authentication Provider:

Edit Identity Pool > Expand Authentication Provider tab > Cognito tab > Added my User Pool ID and App Client ID to the required fields.

My code snip to handle login is as follows:

```
private AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider;
    public AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient Provider
    {
        get
        {
            if(provider == null)
            {
                provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(cognitoAWSCredentials, Constants.REGION_ENDPOINT);
            }

            return provider;
        }
    }

    private CognitoUserPool userPool;
    public CognitoUserPool UserPool
    {
        get
        {
            if(userPool == null)
            {
                userPool = new CognitoUserPool(Constants.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, Constants.AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID, Provider);
            }

            return userPool;
        }
    }

    private CognitoAWSCredentials cognitoAWSCredentials;
    public CognitoAWSCredentials CognitoAWSCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            if (cognitoAWSCredentials == null)
            {
                cognitoAWSCredentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(Constants.AWS_COGNITO_USER_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, Constants.REGION_ENDPOINT);
            }
            return cognitoAWSCredentials;
        }
    }

    private async void GetAWSCredentials()
    {
        string accesstoken = string.Empty;

        // Try to find user;
        CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(usernameField.Text, Constants.AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID, UserPool, Provider);
        InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
        {
            Password = passwordField.Text
        };

        try
        {
            AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;

            if(message == "User does not exist.")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", message, "Ok");
            }
            else if(message == "Incorrect username or password.")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Incorrect password.", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again.", "Ok");
            }

            loginButton.IsEnabled = true;

            return;
        }

        CognitoAWSCredentials.AddLogin("www.amazon.com", user.SessionTokens.IdToken);
    }
```

When ever I try to consume any other AWS service (in this case DynamoDB) using the above code I keep getting the following error message:

"ERROR|NotAuthorizedException making request GetIdRequest to https://cognito-identity.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/. Attempt 1. --> Amazon.CognitoIdentity.Model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token."

How do I authenticate a user correctly using AWS Cognito for Xamarin?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The following thread maybe helpful to you:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/114643/how-to-user-aws-cognito-to-sign-in-and-sign-up-users

Comment: @CherryBu that is actually my own thread. The issue isn't the login. I am able to enter a username and password and get an authentication successful response from aws but after that my token becomes invalid when I try to access any other aws services.